# Encrypting with crypto. Encrypt fails, decrypt works perfectly

Tags: java, android, encryption, mcrypt

**MCrypt:**

```
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public class MCrypt {

            private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";
            private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
            private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
            private Cipher cipher;

            private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";

            public MCrypt()
            {
                    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

                    keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

                    try {
                            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
            {
                    if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
                            throw new Exception("Empty string");

                    byte[] encrypted = null;

                    try {
                            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

                            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {                       
                            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    return encrypted;
            }

            public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
            {
                    if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
                            throw new Exception("Empty string");

                    byte[] decrypted = null;

                    try {
                            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

                            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return decrypted;
            }



            public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
            {
                    if (data==null)
                    {
                            return null;
                    }

                    int len = data.length;
                    String str = "";
                    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                                    str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                            else
                                    str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                    }
                    return str;
            }


            public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
                    if (str==null) {
                            return null;
                    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
                            return null;
                    } else {
                            int len = str.length() / 2;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                                    buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
                            }
                            return buffer;
                    }
            }



            private static String padString(String source)
            {
              char paddingChar = ' ';
              int size = 16;
              int x = source.length() % size;
              int padLength = size - x;

              for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
              {
                      source += paddingChar;
              }

              return source;
            }
    }
```

**Main:**

```
mcrypt = new MCrypt();
/* Encrypt */
String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt") );
//Returns 9975e28df055c336a9b7090b03f88689
/* Decrypt */
String decrypted = new String( mcrypt.decrypt( encrypted ) );
//Returns "Text to Encrypt "
```

The problem:

`String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Text to Encrypt") );` 
**Encrypt returns:** 9975e28df055c336a9b7090b03f88689 (which is incorrect)
`String decrypted = new String( mcrypt.decrypt( encrypted ) );` 
**Decrypt returns:** "Text to Encrypt " (which properly reflects what the encryption came up with, there is a " " after Encrypt)

I've narrowed it down to this line:
`encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());`

I tried changing the padString function so that `char paddingChar = 0;` instead of `char paddingChar = ' ';` with no luck...

When properly encrypted "Text to Encrypt" should turn into "cb4b4ca864213684070465b38783a6c8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES is a block cypher.  It encrypts one 256 bit block (=16 bytes) into a different 256 bit block.  Your plaintext, "Text to Encrypt" is 15 characters, or 248 bits.  AES cannot encrypt it as-is, but must add some padding to make it up to a full block.

If you explicitly add a padding character, then you must explicitly remove it.  Each different padding character will have a large impact on the decryption.  On average, changing one bit in the input plaintext block will change 50% of the bits in the output cyphertext block.

Your easiest solution is to use the buit in padding facilities in Java.  You specify your cipher as: `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"`.  Change this to `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` for both encryption and decryption.  Don't worry about what the cyphertext looks like, just check that the plaintext matches the decyphered cyphertext, character for character.

A common error is to convert a text string to a byte array using `getBytes()`.  Don't do that, because it is error-prone.  You should specify precisely what mapping you are using between characters and bytes.  Use something like:

```
byte[] plainBytes = plaintextString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

and similar at the other side.  Do not rely on system defaults always being the same.

Comment: Excellent answer covering both padding and the pitfalls of unspecified encodings. :)

Comment: I looked into, but I'm still having the same initial problem. The initial problem is that the encrypt on my phone isn't encrypting properly. Even when i send "Text to Encrypt " which is exactly 16chars, and I remove the pad function, it produces an encrypted string that doesn't match the encryption I'm getting from a PHP script executing the same encryption. I tried getting PHP to use PKCS5PAdding, but the functions themselves don't support it. Even when I found a custom workaround the encryption from the phone and php still don't match, which lead me to think the phone is still having issues.

Comment: Basically something is going wrong on the java side and I'm not sure what it is. It might be the hex2bin function, but I don't think it's the padding. Maybe it's the way I'm setting up my crypto. I also found your suggestion about "UTF-8" and I've been using that, still no changes. I used `Charset.defaultCharset()` on my phone and got `com.idm.icu4jni.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]` and I checked the php server, it uses `Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3` so I think they're both using the same charset. Not sure what else could be messing this up.

Comment: Unless you are very careful about defaults, you would not expect to get the same cyphertext.  For example, are you using the same IV (bit-for-bit the same) each time?  Basically, don't worry about the cyphertext, just make sure that the plaintext comes through the same.  Also remember that a 16-char plaintext may well be padded to 32 chars in some padding schemes.

Comment: HOLY S*** I got it to work. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of PKCS5Padding, that definitely cut out a lot of error. Thank so you much sir. God sometimes I freaking love stackoverflow because this community solves so many problems xD